# Join function not working for horizontal ranges?

Tags: excel, vba, delimiter

I'm want to convert a range to a string with a custom delimiter with the Join function, while this worked for a vertical range I haven't been able to do it for an horizontal one. This what worked for a column/vertical range:

```
Join(Application.Transpose(Workbooks("Book3").Sheets(1).Range("A1:A5").value), ";")
```

Now when I try the same with a horizontal range I get the error "Invalid procedure call or argument"

```
Join(Application.Transpose(Workbooks("Book3").Sheets(1).Range("A1:D1").value), ";")
Join(Workbooks("Book3").Sheets(1).Range("A1:D1").value, ";")
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose( _
      Workbooks("Book3").Sheets(1).Range("A1:D1").value)), ";")
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't run into limits on the number of cells that can be Transposed, you can try a function like this:

```
Function JoinRange(rg As Range, Optional Delim As String = " ")
Dim V As Variant

V = rg
If UBound(V, 1) = 1 Then 'One Row
    JoinRange = Join(WorksheetFunction.Index(V, 1, 0), Delim)
Else
    JoinRange = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(V), Delim)
End If
End Function
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'd suggest using ElseIf to check that there is a single column:     ElseIf (UBound(arr, 2)) = 1 Then

Comment: @Jane I went back and forth over whether to test for multiple rows/columns.  As written, it will return a `#VALUE!` error if there are multiple columns or rows.  I don't know if that is sufficient for the OP's purpose, but it is easily changed.